# Google Maps Link on Website doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am unable to load Google Maps from my website using local host. The search string works when pasted into my browser URL but not from ASP vb code using a link button. The first click does nothing. The second click shows a Google Error page that the address is too long. I have tried various strings with code, but nothing works. Am I missing something from Google to make it work?

Comment: can you provide more details to help you, what you have tried so far

Comment: I just found the solution. Using the link button just does not work. So, I used a button with code to redirect the page. And a bit of java script to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might helps you..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Show Google Map with Latitude and Longitude in asp.net website</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map_canvas {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var lat = document.getElementById('txtlat').value;
                var lon = document.getElementById('txtlon').value;
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon) // This is used to center the map to show our markers
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    marker: true
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Latitude:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtlat" value="13.053147716796578" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Longitude:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtlon" value="80.2501953125" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: initialize()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```